# Amplifier overheating - how to find out if A671 PNP transistor broken?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, amplifier

I have a beautiful old Wega V 3840-2 amplifier. However, it has suddenly given out. I have some basic tools (soldering tools + multimeter: I'm a mechanical engineer, so I'm afraid I don't have my own oscilloscope), so I was wondering if I could somehow nurse it back to life.

The problem is that while listening to some music, the right audio channel suddenly gave out, and is instead playing a nice and soft 100 Hz hum, regardless of any volume or input. At the same time, I can feel one of the right channel main amplifying transistors heats up significantly within a few seconds, despite being attached to a massive heat sink. So, I know have two scenarios: either the 'hot' transistor broke down, or something upstream of the transistor is. The latter scenario is supported by the fact that sometimes, after a few seconds the transistor springs back to life with a slight crackle on the speakers. This would suggest a broken capacitor somewhere long the way, as far as I know.

My question is **how do I determine where the problem lies**: in the transistor or upstream?

Some additional details: the main amplifying stage seems to consist of a two-stage amplifier: a C1061 and A671 (PNP) transistor. The latter transistor is the one that heats up significantly. No other components seam to heat up. No components have visual indications of damage.

Comment: I would remove power from the system, then use the multimeter to check for short circuits to ground around the "hot" parts. There may be some valid ground contacts around there, but maybe you'll find one which does not look right. Next i'd replace the chip which gets hot. Good luck! Also, this site is not kind to those looking for help repairing electronics..

Comment: You have left and right - do comparative voltage measurements at the same circuit points.

Comment: If it comes and goes, suspect a dry solder joint. Look for grey granular ones and re-solder them.

Comment: @KyranF I had a sneaking suspicion that this question might be considered off-topic (I wouldn't be personally offended by a close vote), but I tried to keep it general by asking how to determine whether a transistor is faulty so that others can apply the answers given to their own problems. We'll see :) Either way, the comments you and others gave will give me something to work on.

Comment: I think @BrianDrummond has a good point there, especially because the chip could get so hot that the poor solder joint recovers after a few seconds, but then will return to a poor solder joint after using it, making the next start-up a bad one again.

Comment: @KyranF Does a disconnected base/collector/emitter cause overheating, then? (This was actually the reason I figured the question might still be on-topic; I imagined answers along the lines of *an overheating transistor is caused by incorrect biasing*)

Comment: I would say the base connection of the PNP transistor is having a bad time, and until it heats up and reflows, the collector-emitter is just passing current (and heating up) while oscillating at 100Hz which you hear while it's in this condition.

Comment: Tip: if you need to replace parts, these are Asian/Japanese transistors. The actual type (and thus datasheets) are obtained by prefixing a 2S, i.e. 2SC1061, 2SA671 etc. Those transistors are push-pull stage most likely, not two stages as you say.

Comment: The 100 Hz you hear could be mains PSU ripple which could mean that its pulling way too much current .be careful !.

Comment: @KyranF Nope. First, I re-soldered the transistors, didn't work, so then I replaced them with modern equivalents, but to no avail. Blew a nearby diode (thermal protection diode?) too, so now the humming never stops. I guess this question can be closed, and I'll see where else I can find help with this.