# Varistor equivalent

Tags: identification, datasheet, varistor

I am repairing an old Marantz stereo amplifier and have come across a varistor MV11Y that appears to be the issue.

Is anyone able to advise/send me the data sheet for this varistor or perhaps let me know an equivalent part?

Comment: Was it screwed to a heat sink?

Answer (score 2):

This Ohimuzi MV-11Y is used for temperature-compensated biasing. It consists of one or more diodes in series (I think just two for this one).

They aren't produced anymore, but sometimes seen on Ebay et al. at very steep prices.

I have no idea about the specs, but it is often replaced by one or more 1N4148s or other diodes in series (two for this one) by the audio equipment restauration people.

Also see "[What can I use to replace an SV-04F bias diode?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/243654/what-can-i-use-to-replace-an-sv-04f-bias-diode)" for discussion of a similar component. You could also try audio repair sites for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a Harman Kardon amplifier, so, just in case still works: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nte-electronics-inc/NTE605A/13968207?s=N4IgTCBcDaIHIBUCiA2ADAVgIIgLoF8g

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that answer. Just to be clear: Do you know that the part you linked has the same specification as the MV11Y? If so, can you give more details of how you confirmed that? Or did you just repair your amplifier successfully with the linked part, so that suggests that it is "close enough" to the specification of the original one? Thanks.